# Accessing variables from one variable group to other in VSTS

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

As part of a POC, I am trying to set a environment variable in a powershell script from AgentPhase1 and trying to access and print the same variable in AgentPhase2 of a VSTS release pipeline. But, I always get below exception.

Exception Message: 'BuildConfiguration' is either empty or undefined

Is there any way to pass variables between multiple agent phases. My Code to set variable in AgentPhase1

`$csv='1','2','3'
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildConfiguration]$csv"`

Code to fetch and print the variable in AgentPhase2

`Write-Host 'Reading data from AgentPhase2' $env:BuildConfiguration`

**EDIT**
I am able to access and print 'BuildConfiguration' variable within the same Agent Phase, but I cannot read the same variable in other Agent Phases.

Any help...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The changed value of the variable only works for the environment which you change the value**, not other environments and AgentPhases.

The work around is **add a Powershell task for each AgentPhase/environment** which you need to get the changed value. The powershell script is the same as you set:

```
$csv='1','2','3'
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BuildConfiguration]$csv"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Maria, Could you let me know if there are any other variable types which have higher precedence/scope than environment variables which we can use to access between agent phases?

Comment: There have variable types as: **environment variable** (for a environment), **release variable** (for environments in a release definition), **group variable** (for all the build/release definitions).And group variable has the highest scope, but for the changed value of a group variable, it only works for a certain environment. If you need to use the changed value for other environments/AgentPhases, you should add the powershell task too.